# Best way to divide an std::vector into N pairs of iterators with the range `Y`

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I have a *huge* vector, that I need to process in different threads, so instead of creating N different vectors with the same data, I thought of using iterators for that. I`ve managed to do the code, but it seems to me that it could be shortened or improved.

```
        Iterator begin = vec.begin();
        Iterator end;
        Iterator endOfVector = vec.end(); 

        while(end != endOfVector){
            end = begin;

            advance(end, elementsPerThread);
            if (end > endOfVector){
                end = endOfVector;
            }

            iteratorPairs.push_back( std::make_pair(begin, end) );

            begin = end;
        }
```

I`m way used to C++/Qt programming, but when it comes to std:: I feel that I still got a lot to learn. :)

Comment: That seems fine to me (with the caveat that you have to be supercareful not to invalidate any iterators while your threads are working on the vector!). What do you not like about it?

Comment: too verbose. :) something like  ` iteatorPairs = split( vec, 8);` was something that I was looking for. =p

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd do it a bit differently. Instead of checking whether we've passed the end of the vector every time, I'd probably start by computing the number of pairs that are going to fit. As long as we're at it, we might as well try to to fit them as well as we can -- for example, let's assume we had a maximum of 100 elements per thread, and 550 elements total. The way you're doing it, we'd end up with 5 ranges of 100 elements each, and one range of 50 elements.

If we're going to have 6 ranges total, we'd typically rather distribute the workload as evenly as we can over those 6 ranges, so we do 550/6 = 91 or 92 elements per range (and one range with an odd size to make up the difference).

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator it;   
typedef std::pair<it, it> p;

std::vector<p> split(std::vector<int> const &v, size_t elementsPerThread) {
    std::vector<p> ranges;

    size_t range_count = (v.size()+1) / elementsPerThread+1;
    size_t ePT = v.size() / range_count;

    size_t i;

    it b = v.begin();

    for (i=0; i<v.size()-ePT; i+=ePT)
        ranges.push_back(std::make_pair(b+i, b+i+ePT));

    ranges.push_back(std::make_pair(b+i, v.end()));
    return ranges;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this difference on the size of the iterators right now, since in my current problem I have around 900 itens per thread, and the last thread gets around 10 itens.. :) thanks. your sollution is very good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is

```
advance(end, elementsPerThread);
```

The reason is that advance would go past the end of the vector resulting in undefined behavior. I would replace

```
        advance(end, elementsPerThread);
        if (end > endOfVector){
            end = endOfVector;
        }
```

With

```
advance(end,std::min(elementsPerThread,endOfVector - end));
```

Then advance will not go past the end of the vector